# Move layers to coordinates from text file - Photoshop scripting

Tags: scripting, coordinates, move, photoshop, layer

1. I have a base layer - a map of Europe.
2. a bunch of "country" layers representing each country goes on top of the base layer.
3. I have a text file with the x/y coordinates of the top left corner of where each the country is to be placed, in relation to the base layer. The coordinates list is in pixel values separated with commas. And some of the values is negative as well.

So what I want to do is move each country layer according to the coordinate list.

Using Javascript I have been able to load the text file, but I am at a loss how to pass the coordinates to each layer and actually move the layers into place.
I cant seem to add a picture here or even a link - just get an error message.
Trying a hyper link: [Link to image][1]
Sergey Kritskiy , Ghoul Fool - Thank you for all your patience and help with this.

This is what I have for "Code" as of now - lots missing..

````
main();

var originalUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

function main(){
   //declare listFile variable, prompt to browse for text file
   var listFile = File.openDialog("Open list of coordinates","text(*.txt):*.txt;"); 
   //if no file selected, return
   if(listFile == null) return;
   //read the selected text file (listFile) to a string(listString)  - read coordinates from text File
   listFile.open('r') ; 
   var listString = listFile.read();
   listFile.close(); 
   //splitting at line breaks, convert into array of strings
   fileList = listString.split(' ');
   
   //Need to tell what is X-value and what is Y-value
 
   // call the source document
   var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
   var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;

   // main loop
   for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0  ; i--)
      {

   //select that layer as you go along
   srcDoc.activeLayer = srcDoc.artLayers[i];
  
  // Here is where each layer should be paired to its coordinate from the text file - But how to do it? 

   // move the layer
   moveLayer(moveX , moveY);
   }
  }

   //iterate array of strings (coordinates), move layers  acording to coordinates in the loaded text document                 
   //for(var i=0; i<=fileList.length; i++){
   //    var theFile =new File(fileList[i]);
   }
};```


 [1]: https://www.mediafire.com/view/oms4kv7kt6l6zsf/coordinates_list_and_layers.JPG/file
````

Comment: Have you checked photoshop javascript scripting reference? Text layers have a `.position` property

Comment: Thank you, I have but I need more guidance than it gives as I am a beginner with JavaScript. Maybe this project is too complicated for a beginner? - Also I am not trying to move text layers, but image layers. The coordinates is in a text file.

Comment: There's an answer you might want to look into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487476/photoshop-how-to-handle-numbering-a-large-amount-of-disorganized-items/32499267#32499267 code in there creates new text layers and position them, some bits might be useful to you. However you might want to ask more specific questions (explain your psd file structure, your data structure, what exactly you have issues with)

Comment: My file structure is explained in points 1. and 2. of my post.  My data structure is explained in point 3. My problem is how to pair up coordinates from the coordinate list with each of the layers in the .psd and move the layers to the "paired" coordinates. What is the unclear parts please?

Comment: How to pair the coordinates: maybe by name, maybe by layers hierarchy. Depends on structure of your psd and coordinates list, the code you already have — which you don't want to provide for some reason. "I have a list" isn't a structure.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I will addsome screenshots of the coordinate list and .psd when I get home. The coordinates list format is X-value (in pixels) "," Y- value (in pixels) - One coordinate set on each line. - values are in relation to where they should be placed on the base image. My code at this point isn't really much to speak of.. but I will be happy to post what I have..

Comment: ok! please mention me here and I'll take a look when you update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want a function to translate a layer (from its original position to its intended position)

You'll also need to work in pixels, which'll make life easier.

You'll either have an object on an array of countries with their respective offsets.

Loop over all the layers. See if the layer name matches a country. It does? Then move that layer.

This'll give you a rough idea, but only works with maps from 1883 where Lichtenstein was the only known country in the world, which naturally made mapping easier.

```
var originalUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;


// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;

// main loop
for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0  ; i--)
{

  //select that layer as you go along
  srcDoc.activeLayer = srcDoc.artLayers[i];

  if (srcDoc.artLayers[i].name == "Lichtenstein")
  {
    var moveX = 100;
    var moveY =  40;

    // move the layer
    moveLayer(moveX , moveY);
  }
}



// Put unit preferences back
app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalUnits;


// FUNCTION moveLayer (dx, dy) translates layer by dx, dy
function moveLayer(dx, dy)
{
  // =======================================================
  var id9297 = charIDToTypeID( "move" );
  var desc2040 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id9298 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref1412 = new ActionReference();
  var id9299 = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
  var id9300 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var id9301 = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
  ref1412.putEnumerated( id9299, id9300, id9301 );
  desc2040.putReference( id9298, ref1412 );
  var id9302 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var desc2041 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id9303 = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
  var id9304 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc2041.putUnitDouble( id9303, id9304, dx );
  var id9305 = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
  var id9306 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc2041.putUnitDouble( id9305, id9306, dy );
  var id9307 = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
  desc2040.putObject( id9302, id9307, desc2041 );
  executeAction( id9297, desc2040, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

So putting it all together you want something like this:

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // OFF 

var originalUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;


main();



function main()
{
   //declare listFile variable, prompt to browse for text file
   var listFile = File.openDialog("Open list of coordinates","text(*.txt):*.txt;"); 
   //if no file selected, return
   if(listFile == null) return;
   //read the selected text file (listFile) to a string(listString)  - read coordinates from text File
   listFile.open('r') ; 
   var listString = listFile.read();
   listFile.close(); 
   //splitting at line breaks, convert into array of strings
   fileList = listString.split("\n");

   
   //Need to tell what is X-value and what is Y-value
 
   // call the source document
   var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
   var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;

   // main loop
   var c = 0;
   // ignore the background? Start at numOfLayers -2
   for (var i = numOfLayers -2; i >= 0  ; i--)
   {

      //select that layer as you go along
      srcDoc.activeLayer = srcDoc.artLayers[i];
      var theLayerName = srcDoc.artLayers[i].name;
      var line = fileList[c].split(",");
      var moveX = line[0];
      var moveY = line[1];

      // alert(theLayerName + " : " + moveX + ", " + moveY);


     // Here is where each layer should be paired to its coordinate from the text file - But how to do it? 

      // move the layer
      moveLayer(moveX , moveY);

      // increment the file list counter
      c+=1;
   }
}

// set ruler units back to how it was
app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalUnits;


// Set Display Dialogs back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL


// FUNCTION moveLayer (dx, dy) translates layer by dx, dy
function moveLayer(dx, dy)
{
  // =======================================================
  var id9297 = charIDToTypeID( "move" );
  var desc2040 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id9298 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref1412 = new ActionReference();
  var id9299 = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
  var id9300 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var id9301 = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
  ref1412.putEnumerated( id9299, id9300, id9301 );
  desc2040.putReference( id9298, ref1412 );
  var id9302 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var desc2041 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id9303 = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
  var id9304 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc2041.putUnitDouble( id9303, id9304, dx );
  var id9305 = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
  var id9306 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc2041.putUnitDouble( id9305, id9306, dy );
  var id9307 = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
  desc2040.putObject( id9302, id9307, desc2041 );
  executeAction( id9297, desc2040, DialogModes.NO );
```

}

Comment: Thank you Ghoul Fool, this helped me a bit more. I have updated my question with more information now.

Comment: You were nearly there! If you are just doing a corresponding first line of coords moves first layer, second line moves second layer then you just split the string into an array on a new line. And then split that line into two items (X & Y) on the comma.

Comment: Exactly this is my problem - How to link the coordinates to each layer?

Comment: Thank you for all your help! It is really helping me progress with PS-Scripting by seeing how you are going about it. Its just amazing how fast you could do something that took me hours of headscratching:)